# After restore back up from another server panel content not loading in drupal 7 site

Tags: php, drupal-7, content-management-system, panel

I have restored drupal  site one server to another.But the panel content not loading in to it . Only the header portion is loaded .. no further content are loaded in it.Please help

Answer (score 0):

It resolved , The problem occurred with the PHP version. Updated PHP version to 4 above.

Thanks.